# C# get oauth2 token but got 404 Bad request error

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, token

The website help says I should POST below to the endpoint. Then the response will give me a new token.

```
{
  "client_id": "abc",
  "client_secret": "xxx",
  "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
```

I am trying to use this C# to get oauth2 token from a website. But the below codes return '404 Bad Request' error. Is there anything wrong in my code?

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxx.com/api/oauth/token");
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
           

            //write the data to post request
            String postData = "client_id=abc&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=client_credentials";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);
            if (buffer != null)
            {
                webRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
                webRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: The client credentials flow is the correct grant type for getting a machine-to-machine token, so you're on the right path. But we really need more info to diagnose the issue. What is the Identity Provider (B2C, Cognito, Okta, Auth0)? Also, are there any logs from the server that might help narrow down your 'Bad Request' issue?

Comment: How long does it take for error to occur?  You may be getting redirected to a proxy an not finding the proxy.  The timeout for finding a proxy is 30 seconds.

Comment: It is OAUTH2. And the error came back in 2 seconds. So I think it's not redirected. I don't have server side log for now.

Comment: I think maybe the string format is wrong ? String postData = "client_id=abc&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=client_credentials";